# ON CONFLICT syntax error in Postgres 9.5.0

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

In Postgres documentation [INSERT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) there is an example of ON CONFLICT use:

```
INSERT INTO distributors (did, dname) VALUES (7, 'Redline GmbH')
ON CONFLICT (did) DO NOTHING;
```

I try the same thing:

```
INSERT INTO name_map VALUES ('key_value', 'val1','val2') 
ON CONFLICT (key_column) DO NOTHING;
```

But get ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ON".

What am I missing?

```
postgres --version
> 9.5.0
```

Comment: Are you actually _running_ PostgreSQL 9.5? You may have multiple versions installed.

Comment: Sounds as if you are not connected to a Postgres 9.5 server. Post the output of `select version()`

Comment: Is `key_column` indexed?

Comment: You can double check that you are connected to a 9.5 server with `SELECT version()`

Comment: select version() shows in fact that the server running is 9.4.5. Apparently there is a problem when starting postgres. I'll edit the question. Thanks!

Comment: See this question on how to do it in Postgres < 9.5: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-to-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql

Answer (score 12):

As several people pointed out in the comments, it turns out the wrong version of postgres is running.

```
select version()
```

in psql revealed this.

There must be an old installation of 9.4.5 hiding somewhere in my system.